# What do you call this bug and is it a CSS, JS, library bug?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-asp.net-mvc, jqxgrid

I have this bug happening in my site where my menu drops down and instead of being render on top there is this one area that is under the table.

[image]

I am looking for an answer but am not sure exactly what is the bug called, or if it is a CSS, java script, or library problem. The menu is created using [Kendo Ui](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html) and the table/Grid is created using [JqxGrid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?%28arctic%29). If you guys can help me identify the name of this behavior it will help me a lot in finding the solution. Or if you know the reason that is even better. Before I show code I would like to try to solve this on my own. Thank you.

Comment: looks like a z-ordering bug.

Comment: It's difficult to debug without seeing your code. I'm guessing there's a z-index issue or a structural problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like an issue with your CSS. The row of the grid you have is at a higher z-index than your menu. In my experience the best thing to do is to explicitly (where possible) give your menu items z-indices higher than anything else you have on the page (or would want). eg. if your highest z-index is 100, use 1000 for the menu.

Comment: I will look into the z-index thank you.

Comment: Z-index that was the problem my menu had a z-index of 498 and the grid's header had a z-index of 499. Thanks man Idk wth z-index was until now. Cool learn something today :)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

<That is a great resource if you're interested in learning some more, and that site is a great resource in general for CSS tips and tricks. Glad to help :)